# React JS not compiling LESS files

Tags: reactjs, less, antd

I recently was trying to use less as my style sheet to customise components of Ant Design. But each time I try to run and compile the project, a less file in the Ant Component library is showing errors. These errors are not supposed to be errors, as one error stated that a comment symbol in the Less file was unrecognised.
Am I missing something? Also how do I get React working with Less files? Thanks!

```
//App.css

@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';


.site-layout-content {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 24px;
  min-height: 280px;
}

.logo {
  width: 160px;
  height: 31px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  margin: 16px 24px 16px 0;
  float: left;
}

.caution-tape-logo {
  background: url('drawable/ctrclogo.png');
  width: 245px;
  height: 63px;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px 24px 16px 0;
}

.header-space {
  width: max-content;
  height: 31px;
}
```

Here is the error: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhPFR.jpg

Comment: What are the errors it is showing?

Comment: Show me your codes.

Comment: @Meruemu above now

Comment: @Nelles 

https://imgur.com/a/FX4m3J2

Comment: What bundling tool are you using?

Comment: @JoeLissner 
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },

just react

Comment: Have you tried following: https://medium.com/@giordano.cardillo/adding-sass-or-less-support-to-create-react-app-38cbe6c370ce yet?

Comment: let me check, thanks

Comment: @JoeLissner i just tried it, but the files the article has is different from mine.